# Does code snippet support CSS modules?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I want to ask a question related to CSS modules (https://github.com/css-modules).

Is it possible to use CSS module syntax in a snippet? Such as `@value`?

If yes, how can I enable it?

Comment: As a non standard feature I don't expect the SE team would have any interest in supporting this. If it one day got adopted as an official part of CSS, then maybe.